# Parameter of type "has << operator"

Tags: c++, io, stream, iostream

I need to draw my object on an out stream, which is usually `cout`.
But I also want the user to be able to input any stream that has `<<` operator (such as `QTextStream`), so it doesn't have to be `cout` every time.
What's the easiest way to define such parameter?

So this is what I'd like to have, something compilable tho:

```
virtual void draw(GeneralOutStream out = std::cout)
{
    out <<  m_name << std::endl;
}
```

I know I could use templates, *(which is what I'm doing atm.)* but I was hoping there would be a solution that doesn't require templates.
However, the template solution works fine, so basically I'm just curious.

Comment: You can pass a `std::ostream` by reference if your objects inherit from it. If not, I'd go with templates. I also wouldn't add this dependency unless your objects are really streams.

Comment: I'd go with templates. They're only compiled to the specific type only if that type is being used somewhere in your code. You can even have specialized versions for those that don't support the `<<` operator. So it's a better solution IMO.

Comment: A template is required if you want to support *any* stream, because streams are templatized themselves. We are a serious engineers of a mature industry, we have wide characters and streams to support languages of the world! and can even use them sometimes, to our own astonishment...

Comment: Virtual templates, however, do not exist, so it is not entirely clear how your solution works.

Comment: There's no point in using templates here; `std::ostream&` should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of Four approaches.

First, take `std::ostream` as your `GeneralOutStream`, and assume everyone inherits from it.  Maybe write some stuff that wraps a `QTextStream` up in a way that makes it a `std::ostream`.

Second, write a `template` method that takes `GeneralOutStream&& out` and operates on it.  This requires exposing your implementation in your header.  I'd recommend this one.  Quite strongly, but it does mean that `virtual` ends up being pretty useless.

Third, write a type erasure `GeneralOutStream` that exposes the parts of the general out stream you want to interact with within your class with a `template` constructor that stores the passed in generic type in a `pImpl` with `virtual` methods, then use that type within the implementation of your object.  This has runtime overhead and is quite tricky to write, and resembles the pattern of `std::function` -- except `GeneralOutStream` has to handle being able to write an entire myriad of types!

If I was to write #3, `GeneralOutStream` would be a `template` that takes a sequence of types the `GeneralOutStream` is supposed to handle, then does some metaprogramming to expose exactly those overloads to `<<`.  This gets really tricky, because you need to replicate overload resolution manually.

Forth, create an enumeration of "GeneralOutStream" types that you want to support.  Use double-dispatch techniques to ferry references to instances of those types through a `virtual` method call, unbundling them at the other side and calling your implentation `template` methods, requiring that the implementing class handle the entire enumeration.  This one is slightly less tricky to implement than #3, limits what types you can pass to the `draw` method, but allows full access to the type in the implementation `class`.

Comment: I'll have to play a little with these, but I guess I'll just go with the second solution.. :P Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want a solution any *stream* (derived from `std::ostream`) or for *any* object that has `<<` operator?

In the first case, you can pass a reference to the stream object:

```
virtual void draw(std::ostream& out = cout) {
    out << m_name << std::endl;
}
```

Passing a copy won't compile.

In the second case, the main problem is the interface, since it looks you want to define that function as virtual member. If is not the case and you still want a solution for *any* object (not necessary standard `ostream`, but any with operator `<<` defined), you'll have to use templates.

Comment: @n.m.: I know that. When I said "you'll have to use templates", I meant the second case: any object supporting operator `<<` and, of course, without virtual requirement. I've edited the answer to leave it clearer. (Let me know if is still not clear the sense of my answer).